# Why is columnspan not recognized? (Tiknter) The size of the button does not change

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering why when I use the **columnspan** parameter in the .grid() function the button does not change size. Should it not span all columns within the frame? Below I have my code and the output. Thanks all.

```
# Import Modules
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import os


# Basic Structure
root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(600, 700)
root.maxsize(600, 700)
root.title("Training HUB")
root.config(bg="slategray")



# Create Frames - Title, Left and Right Frames
title_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=580, height=50, bg='white', highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
title_frame.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=5)
left_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=280, height=550, bg='white', highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
left_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
left_frame.grid_propagate(0)
right_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=280, height=550, bg='white', highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
right_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)
right_frame.grid_propagate(0)



# Buttons
button1 = ttk.Button(right_frame, text="Run Processing").grid(
    row=0, column=0, columnspan = 2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky = 'ew')



# Run Application
root.mainloop()
```

Tkinter Output:
[image]

Comment: If you want the button to fill the horizontal space inside `right_frame`, you need to call `right_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`.

Comment: thanks! you should right this as an answer with maybe more detail for how it would work for rowspan as well? Then I can accept that answer. @acw1668